# XPages import from excel

Tags: excel, import, xpages

I want to import an excel file using XPages. 
The user can only select an excel file then Javascript codes will handle rest.
I mean it's like a fileUpload window but the file type of file that user can select should be only excel files.

Any suggesstion is important
C.A.

Comment: Maybe this article helps. It shows how you use the Java classes that you get when installing POI4XPages to do an import: http://linqed.eu/2013/12/13/import-excel-files-and-calculations-with-poi-4-xpages/

Comment: does the POI4XPages have apache license. is it possible to use this component for commercial applications?

Comment: Yes, it has an Apache 2.0 license, see: https://github.com/OpenNTF/POI4Xpages/blob/master/LICENCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is about how to restrict the file type, there is a property in the upload control called `accept`

More information http://xpageswiki.com/apps/wiki-xpages/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_a_file_upload_and_download_controls#Limiting+file+types+for+upload

and also it is shown the second image at this link here: https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Limiting_MIME_types_with_IBM_Lotus_Domino_8.5_XPage_file_upload_control#Adding+the+upload+control+to+your+XPage+or+custom+control